# Mac OS 13.5.2 freeze and crash randomly getting more frequent these days

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic, sonoma

My Macbook Pro freezes randomly. The only way is overcome it is to restart manually. It was not that frequent a few months back but it's getting annoying now when I have to work.

I have done everything
NVRAM reset SMC reset, updated to the latest version, and reinstalled OS.
Also did the hardware diagnostic

Expect to remove all the data too. I couldn't find any solution on the web.

**Error Message:**

panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800af95941): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from WindowServer in 120 seconds

**Info**

Macbook Pro 2018 15inch
2.2 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
Mac OS 13.5.213.5.2 (22G91)

````
WindowServer has not exited since first loaded

service: logd, total successful checkins in 20724 seconds: 2067, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

service: WindowServer, total successful checkins in 20690 seconds: 2048, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago

service: remoted, total successful checkins in 20724 seconds: 2065, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

service: opendirectoryd, total successful checkins in 20724 seconds: 2066, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

service: configd, total successful checkins in 20724 seconds: 2066, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Panicked task 0xffffffa519aa4698: 3 threads: pid 112: watchdogd

Backtrace (CPU 2), panicked thread: 0xffffffa04e01b598, Frame : Return Address

0xfffffffd945575b0 : 0xffffff8007c7207d

0xfffffffd94557600 : 0xffffff8007dc6164

0xfffffffd94557640 : 0xffffff8007db5c77

0xfffffffd94557690 : 0xffffff8007c12951

0xfffffffd945576b0 : 0xffffff8007c7235d

0xfffffffd945577a0 : 0xffffff8007c71a07

0xfffffffd94557800 : 0xffffff80083db4d3

0xfffffffd945578f0 : 0xffffff800af95941

0xfffffffd94557900 : 0xffffff800af955dc

0xfffffffd94557920 : 0xffffff800af946b9

0xfffffffd94557a50 : 0xffffff800835280e

0xfffffffd94557bb0 : 0xffffff8007d72909

0xfffffffd94557cc0 : 0xffffff8007c4c51a

0xfffffffd94557d60 : 0xffffff8007c632a2

0xfffffffd94557dd0 : 0xffffff8007c63927

0xfffffffd94557ef0 : 0xffffff8007d9b533

0xfffffffd94557fa0 : 0xffffff8007c12db6

Kernel Extensions in backtrace:

com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[BD08CE2D-77F5-358C-8F0D-A570540A0BE7]@0xffffff800af93000->0xffffff800af95fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffffa04e01b598): watchdogd

Mac OS version:

22G91

Kernel version:

Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul 5 22:21:56 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3~6/RELEASE_X86_64

Kernel UUID: 8295C77B-2AAB-3471-81B5-438F59B1A36D

roots installed: 0

KernelCache slide: 0x0000000007800000

KernelCache base: 0xffffff8007a00000

Kernel slide: 0x00000000078dc000

Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007adc000

__HIB text base: 0xffffff8007900000

System model name: MacBookPro15,1 (Mac-937A206F2EE63C01)

System shutdown begun: NO

Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 20724352621979

Last Sleep: absolute base_tsc base_nano

Uptime : 0x000012d943ad2077

Sleep : 0x000012289adb98b3 0x0000000a4c67297e 0x0000000000000000

Wake : 0x00001228a9cf050e 0x000000005a8710e2 0x00001228a72441af

Compressor Info: 12% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 12% of segments limit (OK) with 7 swapfiles and OK swap space

Zone info:

Zone map: 0xffffff904ca79000 - 0xffffffb04ca79000

. PGZ : 0xffffff904ca79000 - 0xffffff904ea7a000

. VM : 0xffffff904ea7a000 - 0xffffff951b279000

. RO : 0xffffff951b279000 - 0xffffff96b4a79000

. GEN0 : 0xffffff96b4a79000 - 0xffffff9b81279000

. GEN1 : 0xffffff9b81279000 - 0xffffffa04da79000

. GEN2 : 0xffffffa04da79000 - 0xffffffa51a279000

. GEN3 : 0xffffffa51a279000 - 0xffffffa9e6a79000

. DATA : 0xffffffa9e6a79000 - 0xffffffb04ca79000

Metadata: 0xffffffff93f1a000 - 0xffffffffb3f1a000

Bitmaps : 0xffffffffb3f1a000 - 0xffffffffb6f1a000

Extra : 0 - 0

last started kext at 19966002124091: >!UAudio 560.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9d68f000, size 335872)

last stopped kext at 20207994897582: >!UAudio 560.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9d68f000, size 335872)

loaded kexts:

>!APlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0

>AGPM 131

>X86PlatformShim 1.0.0

u/filesystems.autofs 3.0

>!AHIDALSService 1

>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver 6440.7

u/kext.AMDFramebuffer 4.1.4

>!AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.9

u/kext.AMDRadeonX4000 4.1.4

u/kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager 4.1.4

>!ABridgeAudio!C 340.1

>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 7.1.18

>!A!IKBLGraphics 20.0.6

>!AGFXHDA 240.1

u/AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics 7.1.18

>pmtelemetry 1

u/filesystems.nfs 1

|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1

>usb.!UUserHCI 1

>!AHV 1

>!ADiskImages2 198.100.13

>AGDCBacklightControl 7.1.18

>!AMuxControl2 7.1.18

u/kext.AMD9500!C 4.1.4

>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 20.0.6

>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1

>!AMCCSControl 1.16

>!AThunderboltIP 4.0.3

>BridgeAudioCommunication 340.1

>!AAVEBridge 6.1

>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0

>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice 1.0

|SCSITaskUserClient 482.120.2

>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0

>!UMass!SInterfaceNub 554

>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore 1

>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore 1

>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore 1

>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore 1

>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore 1

>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore 1

>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1

u/filesystems.tmpfs 1

u/filesystems.lifs 1

u/filesystems.hfs.kext 627.100.6

u/BootCache 40

@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0

@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1

u/filesystems.apfs 2142.140.9

>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac 1

u/private.KextAudit 1.0

>!AACPIButtons 6.1

>!ASmartBatteryManager 161.0.0

>!ASMBIOS 2.1

>!AACPIEC 6.1

>!AAPIC 1.7

$!AUserConsent 1

@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0

u/nke.applicationfirewall 404

|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1

|EndpointSecurity 1

u/Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0

u/kec.Compression 1

u/kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1

>!AHIDKeyboard 231

>!AHS!BDriver 6440.7

>IO!BHIDDriver 9.0.0

>!AActuatorDriver 6440.7

>!AMultitouchDriver 6440.7

>!AInputDeviceSupport 6460.1

u/kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs 1.0

>!AAudioClockLibs 240.1

u/kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 4.1.4

>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60

>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60

>!AOnboardSerial 1.0

|IOAudio!F 440.2

u/vecLib.kext 1.2.0

u/kext.triggers 1.0

>IOHIDPowerSource 1

>!ACallbackPowerSource 1

|IO!BSerialManager 9.0.0

|IO!BPacketLogger 9.0.0

|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0

|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport 9.0.0

|IO!BHost!CTransport 9.0.0

>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport 9.0.0

|IOAVB!F 1140.6

u/plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 1150.2

|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0

|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0

|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport 9.0.0

>!ARSMChannel 1

|IORSM!F 1

>!AIPAppender 1.0

>!AGraphicsControl 7.1.18

>X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0

u/kext.AMDSupport 4.1.4

>!ABacklightExpert 1.1.0

|IONDRVSupport 597

|IOAccelerator!F2 475.40.6

>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8

>!ASMBus!C 1.0.18d1

>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter 8.5.1

@!AGPUWrangler 7.1.18

@!AGraphicsDeviceControl 7.1.18

|IOGraphics!F 597

|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F 1.0.0

>driverkit.serial 6.0.0

>usb.!UHub 1.2

>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2

>usb.cdc.ecm 5.0.0

>usb.cdc.ncm 5.0.0

>usb.cdc 5.0.0

>usb.networking 5.0.0

>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice 1.2

>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1

>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter 8.5.1

>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F 8.5.1

>!AHPM 3.4.4

>!A!ILpssI2C!C 3.0.60

>!A!ILpssI2C 3.0.60

>!A!ILpssDmac 3.0.60

>!ABSDKextStarter 3

|IOSurface 336.60.1

u/filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1

>!ASyntheticGame!C 10.7.1

>!AXsanScheme 3

>!AThunderboltNHI 7.2.81

|IOThunderbolt!F 9.3.3

>usb.!UVHCIBCE 1.2

>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE 1.0

>usb.!UVHCI 1.2

>usb.!UVHCICommon 1.0

>!AEffaceableNOR 1.0

|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0

|IOBufferCopyEngine!F 1

|IONVMe!F 2.1.0

>!ABCMWLANCoreMac 1.0.0

|IO80211!F 1200.13.0

>IOImageLoader 1.0.0

>!AOLYHALMac 1

|IOSerial!F 11

>corecapture 1.0.4

>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0

|IOUSB!F 900.4.2

>usb.!UXHCIPCI 1.2

>usb.!UXHCI 1.2

>!AEFINVRAM 2.1

>!AEFIRuntime 2.1

>!ASMCRTC 1.0

|IOSMBus!F 1.1

|IOHID!F 2.0.0

|IOTimeSync!F 1150.2

|IOSkywalk!F 1.0

>mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8

|IONetworking!F 3.4

>DiskImages 493.0.0

|IO!B!F 9.0.0

|IOReport!F 47

$quarantine 4

$sandbox 300.0

u/kext.!AMatch 1.0.0d1

>!ASSE 1.0

>!AKeyStore 2

>!UTDM 554

|IOUSBMass!SDriver 235.140.2

|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 482.120.2```
````

Comment: If any peripherals are connected, I suggest you disconnect them and see whether there's an improvement. Otherwise, you're probably dealing with a hardware fault.